# determining how a web app is secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, .net-core

I just "inherited" a web application that uses .NetCore 2.0, NodeJS, and React hosted on a Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.

I'm coming from a linux admin background, and I'm trying to wrap my head around how this web app is secured(which it is).

The site is private and the only public page is the login page. A valid login is required in order to go deeper into the site.

Looking through the code I see that it uses the following name spaces:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication and System.Security.Authentication

Additionally, in the IIS configuration, I see that Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

With that though, I still don't see how it's secure.

I see that in the main javascript file, it has this line:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete((e, jqXHR) => {
    if (jqXHR.status !== HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        return;

    window.location.assign('/govUsers/govLogin?ReturnTo=' +
        encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname));
});
```

I also see that all the API controllers inherit from this controller:

```
//abstract top-level parent class
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
    public class AbstractGovtController : Controller
    {
     protected virtual GovUser CurrentUser => User.GetGovUser(Session) ?? throw HttpException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
    ...
    }
```

The

> GovUser CurrentUser

is used in all the main routes throughout the app so I think that may have something to do with it.

I know when I try to goto some random page via the browser without logging in, it redirects me to the login page with a 302 Found http message.

So my question is, how can I figure out how this app is actually secure?

Thanks!

Comment: all the security is done server side. there's nothing any amount of client side javascript will do to secure anything. the main places to check are the server side routes, to make sure they do not return resources without valid credentials

Comment: Thank you. All the routing is done by react. React uses axios to connect to internal .net api controllers.

Comment: so "routing" done by react is a trick. it's not real "routing". it's just hijacking the browser url and turning it into a global variable. don't be fooled! security can only happen server side in the controllers / .net part of the stack